# Facing a error:TypeError: unbound method get() must be called with WebDriver instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Tags: python, selenium

Here the sample script i have tried

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from ddt import ddt,data,unpack

#@ddt
class search(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver=webdriver.Chrome

    #@data(("Bed & Bath", 12), ("Bags & Luggage", 12))
    #@unpack
    def test_search(self):
        driver=webdriver.Chrome
        driver.get("http://magento-demo.lexiconn.com/")

        def tearDown(self):
            self.driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: The problem is here: `driver=webdriver.Chrome`. You forgot the parentheses. If that makes the answer obvious to you, we can close this as a typo. If it still doesn't make sense, then your problem has nothing to do with Selenium, and you need a basic tutorial on how to use classes and instances in Python, but there may be a duplicate question with answers that help.

Comment: oops  sorry. i just rushed up while pasting the code ...

Comment: actually these is not my question .but i will raised it on next 90 minutes ..but it is very similar to that

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome
```

This doesn't construct a new Chrome webdriver instance, it just assigns `driver` to be a new name for the `Chrome` type. To actually construct an instance, you have to *call* the type:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
```

And of course you have the same mistake in the `setUp` method, and in the different code you posted in [your duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377185/).

---

If you want to understand the error message:

Your `driver` is, again, a name for the type. So when you do this:

```
driver.get("http://magento-demo.lexiconn.com/")
```

… you're not calling `get` on a Chrome webdriver, you're calling it on the type.

Now, it *is* legal to call normal instance methods on a type instead of an instance (this is called "using an unbound method"), but to do that, you have to explicitly pass an instance as an extra argument, for the `self` parameter. You aren't doing that; your first argument is a string (your URL). So, you get this error message:

```
TypeError: unbound method get() must be called with WebDriver instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

It's telling you that if you want to call `get` as an unbound method, the first argument has to be a `WebDriver` instance, not a string.

But really, you don't want to call `get` as an unbound method. You just want to construct an instance properly, then call `get` on that, as a normal bound method.